# My Image slideshow is working great locally until I upload it onto go daddy hosted server

Tags: javascript, html, web, slideshow, web-hosting

My Image slideshow I created in JavaScript works fine locally until I upload it online on hosted Server. I am using Go Daddy. Can anyone help me?

```
    var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000);

}

<img class="mySlides" src="images/Carizmafront.jpg" alt="Carizma shop front"> <img class="mySlides" src="images/Carizmafront2.jpg" alt= "Carizma inside"> <img class="mySlides" src="images/Carizmafront3.jpg" alt= "Carizma inside"> <img class="mySlides" src="images/Carizmafront4.jpg" alt= "Carizma inside">
```

Comment: More information is required to troubleshoot this. If I had to guess, perhaps the relative image path (`images/`) has a different directory context on the server than it did locally. Can you inspect the page in Chrome and see where it's trying to pull the images from?

Comment: Thank you very much the .jpg on the images were in capital letters thank you again!